# How chrome extension download images to extension root directory

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension for the first time.

For my extension, I want it can automatically download images to its extension folder. For example, if the extension folder is `/xxxx/abc/`, I want it can download images to `/xxxx/abc/image/`.

To make it, I don't know how to write file/ download image to this directory. I don't want users notice this.

I found an extension can make it. It's called Momentum. It can download images to `/xxxx/<extension root dir>/backgrounds/`.

Can anybody tell me what technique do I need? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look at that extension code from chrome debugger

Comment: Thanks, I did. But I still didn't find out.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. An extension has only read-only access to own files.

Instead, you can download to a virtual HTML5 filesystem and use files from it. See [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) - the big red warning means no other browser uses this technology, but Chrome does.

You may want to declare `"unlimitedStorage"` permission to make sure you have the space to store the files.

This being a virtual filesystem, those won't actually be files you can open on your disk. If you need to give files to the user afterward, you can use `chrome.downloads` to write them to the downloads folder, but that's "write-only", you can't access the contents afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use HTML5 filesystem. Btw, the Momentum chrome extension can do what I want in some way I don't know.

Comment: To add to this answer, you can actually make it look as if the file is a "regular" downloadable file. If you make a page like chrome-extension://id/files.html?myfile.pdf the page can then provide a link to download the file or even inmediately download it as soon as the link is visited. I have code that does the autodownload without any special permissions.

Comment: @MorganZhang No, it does not. It packs quite a few backgrounds with the extension, but I don't see functionality anywhere to add to them. Note that you can store an image in a virtual filesystem like I described, or even as a `data:` URL in other forms of storage.