# How to download a file to a directory in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Basically the chrome extension I'm making will download an mp3 file, edit the metadata, then download it on the user's machine.

I have the last part done by using `chrome.downloads.download()` (I'm pretty sure I can download a local path instead of a url).

But, I'm not sure how to download a file [like this one](https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/AA0j2im3OByu.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vQUEwajJpbTNPQnl1LjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0ODUwMzU2MzB9fX1dfQ__&Signature=i3vopoSURafWNT7C8t3hHuF1mjMRT9TSKUv3CMdjo3VZUTfkp00RztFM~3Sir0ZDEOn527f1D6XnBBb0L0sE5P1LpCKTk5myj~1pVm-DsUAdCRmoNsEl1EqhwHwCeLgrr6IWcJHula9D4tzKMunsHta164hidrH~K-Cb2F4FEVqsoujw-X45xEQHFRiNrfvJZC9119v4u19T~ORBagJeTq7SP-uuICBz2XMZA1~7XtXOUvJy0ENtYi5-Z8~p9LLeM3Rq5q6G4CP1CpsvFZGLf6dTcxJnokaWhVMhvWmAXXArb4sdl-hy~Qh3umLOmqwZfi8pIVzTIELRb2Sb9naQbw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ) into a directory local to the chrome extension (I don't want the user opening the file before it edits the metadata).

Comment: I believe this question contains your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13752984/1072229.  You only need to focus on `FileSystemApi` for you Chrome extension implementation.

Comment: fetch() the file, save to the filesystem, edit metadata, download() the entry.toUrl(), or skip saving and edit a blob then <a download>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How chrome extension download images to extension root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130260/how-chrome-extension-download-images-to-extension-root-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer: [Broswer ID3 Writer by egoroof](https://github.com/egoroof/browser-id3-writer). This literally does everything I need. What an amazing library!